# Не работает API ozon

Tags: python, api

Делаю POST запрос к API озону, но мне выводится ошибка, и пишет, что нужно вставить параметр который уже стоит в запросе.

```
import requests 

query = {"Client-Id": '',
         "Api-Key": ''}
url = 'https://api-seller.ozon.ru/v3/posting/fbs/unfulfilled/list'

params = {
    "dir": "ASC",
    "filter": {
        "cutoff_from": "2021-08-24T14:15:22Z",
        "cutoff_to": "2021-08-31T14:15:22Z",
        "status": "awaiting_registration",
    },
    "limit": 100,
    "offset": 0
}

response = requests.post(url=url, headers=query, params=params)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: В ошибке пишет нужно передать параметр cutoff, но он передан.

Comment: {"code":3,"message":"the mismatch between cutoff & delivery date","details":[]}

Comment: Не нужно писать в заголовке "решено". Если решили проблему, отметьте свой ответ принятым.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил. Нужно было передавать параметры не в params, а в json.

```
response = requests.post(url=url, headers=query, json=params)
```